# How to bring child field information from parent object with Visualforce page launched from parent layout button?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have this two custom objects called Cuadre__c and Pago__c, Pago__c being a child o cuadre (master-detail).

I have this requirement where I need to launch a Visualforce page from the Cuadre__c layout and load the information from all the related Pago__c's !!

Also, if the user clicks an 'add new line button', a new line of Pago__c should appear for the user to complete some fields from the Pago__c object.

And there should also be a Save button to save the new Pago__c the user might have generated if she or he clicked the 'add new line' button. This Pago__c should save to the realted Cuadre__c from where the Visualforce was called.

Ok, this is my logic so far:

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Cuadre__c" extensions="insertParentChildCon" lightningStylesheets="true" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Agregar pagos al cuadre" >
                <apex:repeat value="{!pagoList}" var="pg" id="table" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!pg.Tipo__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!pg.Importe__c}"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!pg.FormaPago__c}"/>
                </apex:repeat> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add Row" Action="{!AddRow}" immediate="true" id="button"/> 
            
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**:

```
public class insertParentChildCon { 
    
    ApexPages.StandardController sc;
    public List<Cuadre__c> cuadreList {get;set;}    
    Cuadre__c cuadre {get;set;}   
    public List<Pago__c> pagoList {get; set;}
    
    public insertParentChildCon(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
        //cuadre.Id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        cuadre = new Cuadre__c();
        pagoList = new List<Pago__c>();
        AddRow();                                
    }
    
    
    public Cuadre__c getCuadre() {
        return cuadre;
    }
    
    public PageReference AddRow() {
        pagoList.add(new Pago__c());
        return null;
    } 
    
    public PageReference Save() {
        upsert cuadre;
        
        List<Pago__c> pagos = new List<Pago__c>();
        if(cuadre != null) {
            for(Pago__c pago : pagolist) {
                pago.Cuadre__c = cuadre.Id;
                pagos.add(pago);
            }
        }
        if(pagos != null) { 
            upsert pagoList;
        }
        return null;
    } 
}
```

This is generating this UI:

One row:

[image]

Multiple rows:

[image]

Problem is that the code is not bringing the related Pago__c childs from the Cuadre__c object where I'm clicking the button to launch the Visualforce and I can't figure out how to do it.

I've tried this line in the controller's contructor

**//cuadre.Id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');**

```
public insertParentChildCon(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
        //cuadre.Id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        cuadre = new Cuadre__c();
        pagoList = new List<Pago__c>();
        AddRow();                                
    }
```

but not working ... how can I get the childs from the Cuadre__c object in my VF so I can edit the fields, save them, upsert them, etc etc ??

Thanks a lot for reading and helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting any child records because you need to query them first. Query records in controller (add all missing fields) and you are good to go.

```
public insertParentChildCon(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.sc = sc;
        //cuadre.Id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        cuadre = new Cuadre__c();
        pagoList = new List<Pago__c>();
        Id cuId = sc.getId();
        pagoList = [SELECT ID FROM Pago__c WHERE Cuadre__c =: cuId ];
        AddRow();                                
    }
```